# Need help iterating through a nested list but

Tags: iterator, nested-loops

'''

```
patients = [[175.8, 73.4], [180.2, 59.5], [165.4, 70.2], [193.5, 120]]

def calculate_bmi(height, weight):
    return weight / ((height / 100 )**2)

def get_bmi_category(bmi):
    if bmi < 18.5:
        return "underweight"
    elif bmi < 25.0:
        return "normal weight"
    elif bmi < 30:
        return "overweighting"
    else:
        return "obesity"

for patient in patients:
    height, weight = patients[0]
    bmi = calculate_bmi(height, weight)
    bmi_category = get_bmi_category(bmi)
    print("Patient's BMI is: {} ({})".format(bmi, bmi_category))
```

'''

When I print, I only get the results of the first nested list four times, when I want the results of all the nested loops. What else can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem is with the following line of code

```
 height, weight = patients[0]
```

above would only assign values of [175.8, 73.4] to height and weight.
update it as follows

```
height, weight = patient
```

or

```
for height, weight in patients:
#in this case you'll have to remove, height, weight = patients[0]
```

Comment: H! The second option worked! As for the first option, I get a ValueError saying too many values to unpack (expected 2), not sure why that is.

Comment: you are writing "patients", which is your list of lists you should write patient it's without "s", for loop assigns one list from patients to patient iteratively. hence the ValueError. And variable names should be distinct so such mistakes do not happen accidentally. You can practice for loop for list of lists here: https://campus.datacamp.com/courses/intermediate-python/loops?ex=9

Answer (score 0):

Change `height, weight = patients[0]` to `height, weight = patient`.